# Issue when handling arrays in JSON and PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this data in a JSON:

```
"sentences_tone": [
{
  "sentence_id": 0,
  "text": "I hate these new features On #ThisPhone after the update.",
  "tones": [
    {
      "score": 0.637279,
      "tone_id": "anger",
      "tone_name": "Anger"
    }
  ]
},...
```

The problem that at the time of showing the results in PHP, the error appears:

> valor: 0.931034 
>   sentimento: Raiva 
>   texto: It’s just inexcusable. 
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/toneAnalyzer/test.php on line 28

The code is:

```
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$jsonObj = json_decode($result, true);
$i = 0; 
foreach($jsonObj["sentences_tone"] as $value){
    echo 'valor: '.$value['tones'][$i]['score'];
    echo 'sentimento: '.$value['tones'][$i]['tone_name'];
    echo 'texto: '.$value['text'];
    $i++;
};
```

Comment: Please write in English

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: What it says is that you have an undefined offset al line 28. I don't know what the line 28 is, but if i were to guess, I would say it is one of these two: "echo 'valor: '.$value['tones'][$i]['score'];" or "echo 'sentimento: '.$value['tones'][$i]['tone_name'];". ANd it is because your $value['tones'] doesn't have an index 2 (your array is shorter)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, I think the portuguese version would be more appropriate :)

Comment: @Sorix Thanks for providing the link, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments by Sorix, but at best guess the issue you are facing is your loop, you have the following;

```
foreach($jsonObj["sentences_tone"] as $value){
    echo 'valor: '.$value['tones'][$i]['score'];
    echo 'sentimento: '.$value['tones'][$i]['tone_name'];
    echo 'texto: '.$value['text'];
    $i++;
};
```

And from looking at your data, we can see it as such;

```
sentences_tone
    tones
        tone data
```

This means that using the format you have won't work as there isn't an integer index on the tone data, so you just need to drop the `[$i]` from your loop to have the following;

```
foreach($jsonObj["sentences_tone"] as $value){
    echo 'valor: '.$value['tones']['score'];
    echo 'sentimento: '.$value['tones']['tone_name'];
    echo 'texto: '.$value['text'];
};
```

Using the `$i` means it's looking for;

```
sentences_tone
    tones
        0
            tone data
        1
            tone data
        2
            tone data
```

Which just doesn't exist in your data

You can also drop the declaration and increment on the `$i` variable too

Comment: "tones" is an array of objects so the index $i wouldn't pose a problem. What does produce the error is the fact that for each object in "sentences_tone", $i is incremented and then used on the "tones" array. If "tones" is not always an array of size 1, the looping through indexes should be done differently.